# Why am I getting this "Browser is not downloaded" error when running a simple puppeteer script on linux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I've tried downloading the headless browser manually many times and a few other various attempts, but the error persists. Running Linux Mint.

```
                                                                                                                                           
(node:25262) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Browser is not downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn install"
    at ChromeLauncher.launch (/home/oem/web-scraping/puppetering/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:236:15)
(node:25262) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise 
rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25262) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/node

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrape() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://ratings.fide.com/top.phtml?list=men');
    const [ele] = page.$x('//*[@id="main-col"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a')
    const name = await ele.getProperty('text')
    
    console.log(name)
};

scrape()
```

Comment: Have you done what the error is telling you to do? Also, please [edit] your question if you have further information to add.

Comment: yes @HereticMonkey npm install doesnt resolve, nor does attempting to do sudo apt install chromium-browser

Comment: when you do `npm install` does it download chromium? (you should see a progress bar downloading chromium (> 100MB))

Comment: @mbit nope, no trace of a chromium download when running npm install, I've looked in the bin and its not there either, and sudo apt install chromium-browser results in a failed download with 404 errors, --fix-missing wont work as well

Comment: do you use any sort of dns blocking system like pihole?

Comment: @mbit no, no DNS blocking

Comment: my hunch is something is blocking "storage.googleapis.com", dns adblocking systems usually block that. if you couldn't trace the issue, you can just download stable chrome and pass it to the `puppeteer.launch`

Comment: The error persists even after specifying to use '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable' as browser:  const browser = await puppeteer.launch('/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launching puppeteer with chrome instead of bundled chromium:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: '/full/path/to/chrome'
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I have installed puppeteer with the global flag, as root. Then, I started a project as user and got the same problem as your.

Running `npm install puppeteer --save` in the project and as a user triggered the download of Chromium, and solved this error.

No idea why the global install of pupeeter doesn't trigger the same dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Had similar issue while using "magepack". The following commands were help to run it:

```sh
apt-get install chromium-browser
export PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/snap/bin/chromium
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running `npm install` in a container with a CI pipeline, most of the times chromium is not installed.

Try running `npm ci` instead, it always does the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's a install problem. Just follow the steps bellow:

1. Deleted node_modules folder: `rm -rf node_modules`
2. Also delete package-lock.json: `rm package-lock.json`
3. npm install
4. npm start

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in the directory containing *package.json*.

```
node node_modules/puppeteer/install.js
```

This helped me in solving the issue.